# Mapear todos os valores das divs e fazer uma operação matemática

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="product-price">
R$ 140,00
</div>
<div class="product-price">
R$ 165,30
</div>
<div class="product-price">
R$ 12,55
</div>
<div class="product-price">
R$ 25,22
</div>
```

Entre outros valores que seguem a mesma estrutura. Porém, preciso preciso fazer uma função js para que se o valor do produto for menor que R$30, eu não poderei mostrar o número de parcelas para este produto. Se for maior que R$30, eu mostro o número de parcelas.

Minha estrutura js é esta:

```
function calculaParcelaHome(){
    var regex = /\d+,\d+/g;
    var texto = $(".product-price").text(); // pega o conteúdo da div Preco Avista no arquivo products.tpl
    var valor = regex.exec(texto); //converte a string para int
    var insereValor = parseFloat(valor.join("").replace(",",".")); // converte o valor para Float. 
    console.log(insereValor);

    if (insereValor >= 30) {
        $('.parcelas-produtos').css('display','block');
        console.log("Valor maior que 30");
    }else{
        $('.parcelas-produtos').css('display','none');
        console.log("Valor menor que 30");
    }
}
```

Só que na minha função, só consigo fazer a operação para a primeira Div, e não para as demais.

Esta é a estrutura das minhas parcelas:

```
<span class="parcelas-produtos">
                                {l s='3 x de'}
                                {if !$priceDisplay}{convertPrice price=$product.price /3}{else}{convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_exc}{/if}
                            </span>
```

Como poderia fazer esta lógica para as demais?

Comment: Olá Julio, onde são geradas essas parcelas? isso é feito no lado do servidor ou cliente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque seu código em um loop de elementos que você deseja, assim:

```js
function calculaParcelaHome(){
  $('.product-price').each(function() {  
    var regex = /\d+,\d+/g;
    var texto = $(this).text(); // pega o conteúdo da div Preco Avista no arquivo products.tpl
    var valor = regex.exec(texto); //converte a string para int
    var insereValor = parseFloat(valor.join("").replace(",",".")); // converte o valor para Float. 
    console.log(insereValor);

    if (insereValor >= 30) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.parcelas-produtos').show();
        console.log("Valor maior que 30");
    }else{
        $(this).closest('div').find('.parcelas-produtos').hide();
        console.log("Valor menor que 30");
    }
  });
}

calculaParcelaHome();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-price">
R$ 140,00
</div>
<div class="product-price">
R$ 165,30
</div>
<div class="product-price">
R$ 12,55
</div>
<div class="product-price">
R$ 25,22
</div>
```

Comment: Porém dessa forma ele está dando display none em todos os elementos que contêm a classe parcelas-produtos

Comment: Tu quer exibir a parcela do lado do preço? É que o seu html não tava com a clase parcelas-produtos. Pode mandar a estrutura do parcelas-produtos?

Comment: Só posso exibir a parcela do produto se o Valor do product-price for maior que R$30, entendeu?

Comment: Sim, eu entendi, mas como está a sua estrutura do parcelas-produtos?

Comment: Vou editar minha pergunta, olhe lá:

Comment: @JulioRodrigues onde exatamente fica o seu `<span class="parcelas-produtos">`, fica dentro de cada product-price? Eu preciso saber para fazer o caminho certo até ele!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49103/discussion-between-julio-rodrigues-and-juniornunes).

Comment: Perfeita solução! Rodou certinho!